# Advice on posting JavaScript generated content to a file for download as CSV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session, csv

I have some user specific JavaScript generated content I want to post to the server to generate a CSV file that the user can then download.

I have in mind to follow the guidance under **Option 3.1** of the [jQuery Table to CSV Plugin](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php#o6)  but the following occurs to me…

What if 2 or more users are concurrently on the page and using the same functionality? If a generic URL is used for the CSV file (as kunalbabre suggests) is it not possible then that they end up downloading each other's data?

Presumably one should therefore generate a unique URL for the CSV? If so, what methods are best?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered generating your CSV file on the server, instead of on the browser in javascript? I'm pretty sure this would be much easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The CSV is generated dynamically in response to the request. The only file on the server is the PHP program. The CSV file doesn't exist until the browser receives the response and saves it to a file.

Comment: ohh so the plugin creates the file client side?

Comment: +1, and worth adding that the filename shown in the example is for _the user's benefit_ in naming it.

Comment: @ElGabbu The PHP file receives some input and converts it into text -- the same way it would generate a web page -- then it sends it back to the user and says it should be treated as an attachment called "my-data.csv". The file is generated by the server (from the client's information), but it's not _saved_ anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin and Bryan, for such prompt and well explained responses. Good news and very helpful.